# UnauthorizedAccessException in ComRegisterFunction when accessing registry on Win 7 64

Tags: c#, interop, registry, com-interop, browser-extension

I have a [ComRegisterFunction] that I am using to register a BHO Internet explorer extension.  During registration on 64-bit windows 7 machines, a UnauthorizedAccessException 
is thrown on the call to subKey.SetValue("NoExplorer", 1).

The registry appears to have BHO's located @ \HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\Browser Helper Objects, however, I get them same exception when trying to register there.  Any Help would be appreciated.

```
[ComRegisterFunction]
public static void RegisterBho(Type type) {  
    string BhoKeyName= "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";

    RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BhoKeyName, true) ?? 
                              Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(BhoKeyName);

    if(registryKey == null) throw new ApplicationException("Unable to register Bho");

    registryKey.Flush();
    string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");

    RegistryKey subKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid) ?? registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid);

 if (subKey == null) throw new ApplicationException("Unable to register Bho");

 subKey.SetValue("NoExplorer", 1);
    registryKey.Close();
 subKey.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I had to add the following to make it work.  Not sure why it worked in other versions of the OS

```
RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();

rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(user,
            RegistryRights.FullControl,
            InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
            PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,
            AccessControlType.Allow));

RegistryKey subKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid) ??    registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default, rs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run with administrative privileges.

Comment: Yes, but you have UAC enabled.  Right-click, then click Run as Administrator.